# How can i store pushy tokens to database

Tags: java, android, pushy

am using pushy for `push notifications` but am not able to store the `device token` in the `database`.

```
    private class RegisterForPushNotificationsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception> {
    protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Assign a unique token to this device
            String deviceToken = Pushy.register(getApplicationContext());


            // Log it for debugging purposes
            Log.d("MyApp", "Pushy device token: " + deviceToken);

            // Send the token to your backend server via an HTTP GET request
            new URL("https://key}/register/device?token=" + deviceToken).openConnection();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // Return exc to onPostExecute
            return exc;
        }

        // Success
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception exc) {
        // Failed?
        if (exc != null) {
            // Show error as toast message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exc.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // Succeeded, optionally do something to alert the user
    }
}
```

I am using `retrofit` for the `http requests` and am not using any kind of `backend system`

Comment: not using any kind of backend system then where are you trying to save this data?

Comment: Firebase database

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/ it will help you to save data in firebase

Comment: Sorry, if i ddnt explain well. but  what i want is to be able to access the value of  `deviceToken` from outside that class

Comment: Storing to firebase is something i can do but i cant seem to get the value of `deviceToken` even if i declared it as a field, it always returns null

Comment: Did you try using Shared Preferences? If you just want to access outside this class then batter to use Local Shared Preferences

Comment: Is this ```'Log.d("MyApp", "Pushy device token: " + deviceToken);```  printing ```deviceToken``` successfully ?

Comment: yes, it is printing the token

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is well enough to get you a Device Token from Pushy service.

If you want to capture the returned device token and make it accessible to the `AsyncTask` class and the enclosing class in general (as you stated in the comments), then you can declare a global/instance `String` variable, say `pushy_device_token`, in the enclosing class.

Then in `doInBackground()` method of the `AsyncTask`, go ahead and assign the global variable as follows:

`pushy_device_token = Pushy.register(getApplicationContext());`

Complete code:

```js
public class EnclosingClass {
  
  String pushy_device_token;
  
  
  //  Additional class code
  
  
  private class RegisterForPushNotificationsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception> {
  
    @Override
    protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Assign a unique token to this device
            pushy_device_token = Pushy.register(getApplicationContext());


            // Log it for debugging purposes
            Log.d("MyApp", "Pushy device token: " + deviceToken);

            // Send the token to your backend server via an HTTP GET request
            new URL("https://key}/register/device?token=" + deviceToken).openConnection();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // Return exc to onPostExecute
            return exc;
        }

        // Success
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception exc) {
        // Failed?
        if (exc != null) {
            // Show error as toast message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exc.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // Succeeded, optionally do something to alert the user
    }
  }
  
}
```

---

**Best practice recommendation:**

It's best to have the result of processing in `doInBackground()`, returned in the `onPostExecute()` method, especially if you're going to do some UI work. So from `onPostExecute()`, you can do anything you want with the result, e.g. display to the user, report an error, etc.

To do this, you'll have to modify your `doInBackground()` method to return something as generic as `Object`. And so `onPostExecute()` will take in an `Object` as a parameter variable.

You'll modify by:

`private class RegisterForPushNotificationsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> { . . .`

From this, you can check if the `Object` taken in by `onPostExecute()` is of type `Exception`, in which case, you'll display an error notification, or check if it's of type `String`, in which case you'll have the device token which you can then proceed to save in your DB (Firebase, SQLite, etc.).